# Close application when pressed back button with activitie in stack

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments, back

I got 4 Activities and 4 Fragments:

MainActivity -> MainFragment (Which has two buttons, one that goes to RegisterActivity and one for LoginActivity)

RegisterActivity -> RegisterFragment ( After register goes to EventActivity and finish() is called. )

LoginActivity -> LoginFragment ( After login goes to EventActivity and finish() is called. )

EventActivity -> EventFragment -> When pressed back after login or after register it goes back to MainActivity while it should close the appplication.

I can put a finish() call in Mainfragment after they click a button but then if a user goes to Register and it presses the back button it closes the app and I don't want that.

If a user goes to EventActivity and he presses back I want the app to close.

Can anybody give me a solution for this.

Regards,

Comment: EventActivity is the activity where a logged in user should start?

Comment: Yes, I set a boolean in my SharedPreferences so whenever I user start my app and he's already logged in it goes straight to EventActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the flags:

```
setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
```

to the intent starting EventActivity

EDIT:

Assuming you check the preferences flag for the user log in state in MainActivity then the solution is to start MainActivity instead of EventAcivity after a successful login.

Check out a Login/Register flow from [Parse.](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/AnyWall/tree/master/AnyWall-android)

Comment: In my RegisterFragment when you press Register it goes to EventActivity. In that intent I putted  eventActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);    
Still gives me the same problem

Comment: Yes! That's it. When a user succesfully logged in or registered I send him to Mainactivity where the activity checks whether he logged in or not and I putted FLAG_ACTVITYI_CLEAR_TOP to the intent starting it.

Answer (score 0):

// IF Your Registration and login condition successful and you start a new activity

// Use That

```
enter code here
```

Intent intent = new Intent(Registration.this, YourNewActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);